# Lower bound of sum for discrete marginal probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

If we let $(X,Y)$ be two stochastic variables where $X$ has a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda \in(0,1)$ and where $Y$ is binomially distributed with parameters $x$ and $\lambda$ given that $X = x$. We want to find the marginal probability function for $Y$.

In order to do that, a good start is to find the joint probability distrubition, since we from there pretty easily can derive the marginal probability for $Y$.

We know that $P(X = k, Y = l) = P(Y = l | X = k) P(X =k) = \binom{k}{l} \lambda^l (1- \lambda)^{k-l} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda}$ and here $k = {0,1,...}$ wheraeas $l= {0,1,...,k}$

I then want to find the marginal function:

$P(Y=l) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X = k, Y = l)$, however, I'm unsure from which $k$ I need to start from, is this correct or not, and why if so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but notice that because the support is $k \in \{0,1, 2, \ldots \}$ and $l \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, k\}$, this means that we must always have $0 \le l \le k$.  So the sum must be
$$\Pr[Y = l] = \sum_{k=l}^\infty \Pr[X = k \cap Y = l].$$  The lower index of summation must be $l$ since if $k < l$, the event $X = k \cap Y = l$ is impossible to observe.

Consequently $$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y = l] &= \sum_{k=l}^\infty \binom{k}{l} \lambda^l (1-\lambda)^{k-l} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
&= \lambda^l e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=l}^\infty \binom{k}{l} (1-\lambda)^{k-l} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \\
&= \lambda^{2l} e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k + l}{l} \frac{(\lambda(1 - \lambda))^k}{(k+l)!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{2l}}{l!}  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-\lambda))^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda(1-\lambda)} \frac{\lambda^{2l}}{l!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda^2} \frac{(\lambda^2)^l}{l!}.
\end{align}$$
This corresponds to a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda^2$.

We could have also reasoned intuitively:  if $Y \mid X$ is binomial with success parameter $\lambda$, that means we have a hierarchical model of a thinned Poisson process.  Suppose $X$ is a Poisson counting process that observes events with intensity $\lambda$.  Each event independently has a chance to trigger the observation of a secondary event with some probability $p$.  Then the marginal distribution of the secondary events must be Poisson with intensity $\lambda p$.

Think of it this way.  If for each event that is observed, you decide to flip a (possibly biased) coin with probability of heads $p$, then the unconditional number of heads you observe is Poisson with rate $\lambda p$.  The original question simply corresponds to the special case $p = \lambda$.

Comment: Ohh now I see! I'm familiar with the thinned Poisson process, and now I also understand why we constrained ourselves to $\lambda\in(0,1)$ since otherwise we wouldn't be aple to pick that for our $p$ in your last argument. Thanks!!